# Twelve months on, and the nine miracle babies are thriving

Tags: error

Should the boldfaced "and" have been removed in the following?

> The world-famous nonuplets born to a couple from Mali, West Africa have celebrated their first birthday with a small party at home.
>
> Halima Cissé and Abdelkader Arby welcomed five girls and four boys, weighing between just 1.1 and 2.4 pounds, at the Ain Borja clinic in Casablanca, Morocco on May 4 last year.
>
> Twelve months on, **and** the nine miracle babies are thriving and reaching developmental milestones, their father, Arby, shared.

https://edition.cnn.com/2022/05/07/africa/mali-nonuplets-birthday-intl-scli/index.html

Comment: I think it's acceptable as is.  The *and* makes it sound like a casual abbreviation of "**It is now** 12 months on and..."

Comment: Is it idiomatic to say, "Twelve months **later, and** the nine miracle babies are thriving and reaching developmental milestones"?

Comment: It sounds reasonable enough to me.

Comment: Yes, it is completely idiomatic. "Five years later, and the cubs all grew up".

Answer (score 0):

> Twelve months on, and the nine miracle babies are thriving and reaching developmental milestones, their father, Arby, shared.

We could remove the *and*.  The main message would be *the nine miracle babies are thriving and reaching developmental milestones*.

The act of sharing would be another message, but to me is not very significant.

There would be a comma splice, and we could solve it by changing the comma after *milestone* to a semicolon.

> Twelve months on, the nine miracle babies are thriving and reaching developmental milestones; their father, Arby, shared.

I would have written the passage the way shown above.

With the *and*, the sentence would be interpreted differently.  *and the nine miracle babies are thriving and reaching developmental milestones* could be an interruption.  The main message would be *Twelve months on, their father, Arby, shared.*